KiCAD PWR_FLAG issue on DW01A circuit
I am building a TP4056 based battery charger circuit on KiCad. The ERC check throws the error as per the screenshot. Do I need to add the PWR_FLAG on VBAT- and VBAT+ nets as well or is there any other way to solve the ERC?


You can solve it in many ways.
Flagging the BAT- as power node will solve the GND pin issue.
But BAT+ is not connected to VCC pin so flagging the BAT+ won't help. You can flag the node that goes from the VCC pin to the resistor.
